# Как кликнув на изображение-ссылку(map,area) вывести ранее подготовленную сессию на другой странице сайта?Дайте совет пожалуйста

Tags: php, html, url, img

````
session_start();
$_SESSION['chocolate'] = "сладкую"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test3.php</title>    
</head>
<body background="https://mtdata.ru/u29/photoE322/20100658052-0/original.jpg">  
<div align="center">
<table border="3" width="350" height="250" align="center" bgcolor="white">
<tr>
>//это заголовок
<caption><p><h2 align="center"><font color="DarkSlateGray">Какую еду вы любите?</font></h2></p></caption>
>//снизу ссылка на вторую страницу и само изображение
<td><a href="all test2.php" ><img src="https://podacha-blud.com/uploads/posts/2022-12/1671140374_61-podacha-blud-com-p-plitochnii-shokolad-foto-62.jpg" alt="chocolate" width="300" height="200" usemap="#image_map">
>//ниже map, area изображения и строка с текстом 'Сладкую'
<map name="image_map">
 <area alt="chocolate" title="chocolate" href="all test2.php" coords="4,2,1615,1064" shape="rect">
>//Текст "Сладкую как раз и надо вывести через сессию"
</map><div align="center"><b>Сладкую</b></div></a></td><style>a {
width:300px;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
background:grey;
text-decoration:none;
color:orange;
text-align:center;
}</style>
<td>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>```

---

Извиняюсь, на 1 строке session_start(); и в самой сессии нужно отправить текст 'Сладкую'.Ещё я новичок так что если не сложно можно поменьше кода.
````